# how to abort a seq in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a seq like this:

```
let data =
    seq {
        for i in source do
            do some stuff...
            yield result
    }
```

But I would like to turn it into a Result object and, during the iteration I have some conditions that mean an error. For example:

```
let data =
    seq {
        for i in source do
            do some stuff...
            if a > b then .. let's abort everything and return error
            yield result
    } |> Ok
```

The calculations are quite expensive, so it'd prefer not to wrap the yield with Option / Result and sort it out later if I can abort early.

Or, if I do that, how could I iterate until it either completes, or returns an error?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe to `Seq.takeWhile` and sort out there if the `Seq` should be aborted:

```
let data =
    source
    |> Seq.map (fun s -> ... do some stuff ...)
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun r -> ... return false if error ...)
```

`Seq<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>` so it is lazy, calculations are done when new items are pulled out of it.

Edit:

To know if there was an error or if we reached the end of the seq I would traverse it using a fold - so that a seq of "source" items are calculated on the fly and if there is an error then pass through the rest without running the calculation. Here's an example:

```
let source = seq { 
  1
  2
  3
  4 }

let expensiveCalc item =
  printfn "expensiveCalc called with %i" item
  if item > 2 then Error (sprintf "%i is too high" item)
  else Ok item

let traverse valuesResult newSourceItem =
  valuesResult
  |> Result.bind (fun values ->
      expensiveCalc newSourceItem
      |> Result.map (fun newResult -> newResult::values))

let endResult =
  source
  |> Seq.fold traverse (Ok [])

match endResult with
| Ok values -> printfn "%A" values
| Error error -> printfn "%s" error
```

As you can see any number greater than 2 is considered an error, and when running it stops calling `expensiveCalc` after the first error.

Comment: if my yields returns a Result, I can use the takeWhile to keep pulling data until Error is reached, but how would I differentiate the end of the Seq from an error reached?

Comment: @Thomas

I'd fold over source then and calculate on the fly. The downside with this, I guess, is that the whole source seq is drained. See edit.

Comment: so you end up doing all the calculations then? like wrapping everything in Option and checking for None at the end and if it's not found run Choose to get the data

Comment: @Thomas
No, the calculations are only done until the first error occurs, but the whole source seq (before calculations) are drained. Run the second code sample above and you will see that "expensiveCalc called with %i" is only printed for numbers 1, 2 and 3 (3 is the error), 4 is never calculated.